# How to make PUT request (cross domain request) using Request object of firefox addon-sdk

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there anyway to make cross-domain PUT request from firefox addon-sdk, **request** object? If not, what is the best way to do PUT request.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use method PUT? Are there still any servers using it?

Comment: I'm just using the web service API exposed to me by client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `request` package only supports GET or POST - method PUT is pretty much non-existent on the web and I guess that supporting it made no sense. You would need to use the internal `xhr` package that mostly provides the API of a regular [`XMLHttpRequest` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

```js
var {XMLHttpRequest} = require(xhr);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("PUT", "http://example.com/");
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if (request.readyState == 4)
    console.log("request done");
};
request.send(data);
```

Please note that this is internal API and it might change in a future Add-on SDK version.

Comment: Thank you very much wladimir. I will give it a try. Also, can we use jquery.ajax()? Is it supported??